# Navigation property in Entity Framework for a Database Design

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am trying to design a database for a inventory management system. Here is my data-model design in code-first. But there are some issues in the table design, i think.

`Supplier Table`

```
public class Supplier
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }

    [Index, MaxLength(50),Display(Name="Company Name"),Required]
    public string ComapnyName { get; set; }

    [Index, MaxLength(50),Display(Name="Contact Person"),Required]
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "ntext"),Required]
    public string Address { get; set; }

    [Required,Display(Name="Mobile Number")]
    public string MobileNumber { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Land Line Number")]
    public string LandLineNumber { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress),Display(Name="Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    public DateTime? Date_From { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    public DateTime? Date_To { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

`Category Table`

```
public class Category
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required,Index,MaxLength(50),Display(Name="Category Name")]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "ntext"),Display(Name="Category Description")]
    public string CategoryDesc { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    public DateTime? Date_from { get; set; }

    [HiddenInput]
    public DateTime? Date_to { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Supplier> Suppliers { get; set; }
}
```

What is want here is as follows: [In Category Table]A Single category can have multiple products and for a single category there can be multiple supplier.
[In Supplier Table] A single Supplier can supply multiple products and also can supply in multiple categories.

But my table design does not facilitate this scenario. How to correct this ? Any help would be appreciated.

NOTE: If you required any other information please let me know.

`Product`

```
public class Product
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; } //Uniquely identifies product

    [Required, Index(IsUnique = true), MaxLength(50), Display(Name = "Product Name")]
    public string ProductName { get; set; } //Product Name

    [Required, Column(TypeName = "ntext"), Display(Name = "Product Description")]
    public string ProductDesc { get; set; } //Product Description

    [Required,Display(Name="Select Warehouse location")]
    public int WarehouseId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("WarehouseId")]
    public virtual Warehouse warehouse { get; set; }

    [Required,Display(Name="Category of the Product")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; } //Identifies product category

    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual Category category { get; set; }

    [Required,Display(Name="Select Supplier of this product")]
    public int SupplierId { get; set; } //Identifies product supplier

    [ForeignKey("SupplierId")]
    public virtual Supplier supplier { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "Quantity Per Unit")]
    public int QuantityPerUnit { get; set; } //Product quantity per unit

    [Required, Display(Name = "Unit Cost Price")]
    public decimal UnitCostPrice { get; set; } // Product unit price

    [Required, Display(Name = "Unit Selling Price")]
    public decimal UnitSellingPrice { get; set; } // Unit Selling price

    [Required, Display(Name = "Unit Weight in KG")]
    public int UnitWeight { get; set; } // Product unit weight

    [Display(Name = "Unit Size")]
    public string UnitSize { get; set; } // Product unit size, S, M, L

    [Display(Name = "Any discount on this product")]
    public decimal Discount { get; set; } // Discount offered by supplier

    [Required, Display(Name = "Unit in Stock")]
    public int UnitInStock { get; set; } //Product units in stock

    [Display(Name = "Unit in Order")]
    public int UnitInOrder { get; set; } // units in order from supplier

    [Display(Name = "Reorder Level")]
    public int ReOrderLevel { get; set; } // Product margin for re-ordering

    [Display(Name = "Note")]
    public string Note { get; set; } // Some note for product

    public bool Active { get; set; } //to mention if this product is being active/dis-continued by the company

    [HiddenInput]
    public DateTime? date_from { get; set; } //date when this product was added

    [HiddenInput]
    public DateTime? date_to { get; set; } //date when this product was discontinued by company
}
```

Above is the product class model. I think from product class model itself i can extract which product was supplied by which supplier and categories of the each product that was supplied by each supplier?

Comment: i would rather to design this issue database-first. Easier than code-first

Comment: Does product belong to a single category? Are suppliers limited somehow in products/categories?

Comment: @Dennis yes, a product belongs to a single category.

Comment: @Dennis  
I have updated the question. Can you please give your thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to mix reference data, such as "products", their "categories", and "suppliers" with operating data, such as "product, that were supplied".

I'd redesign your entities (and database tables) this way (attributes and scalar properties are omitted):

```
public class Category
{
    // Scalar properties here

    // This navigation property describes "categories-products" hierarchy
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Supplier
{
    // Scalar properties here
}

public class Product
{
    // Scalar properties here

    // This navigation property describes "categories-products" hierarchy
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }         
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}

// This entity describes products, that were supplied by any supplier.
// Note, that we don't need category here, because it can be received through Product.Category reference
public class SuppliedProduct
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // the date and time, when product was supplied
    public DateTime WhenSupplied { get; set; }
    // the quantity for supplied product
    public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
    // who supplied this product
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
    public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    // what product was supplied
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you please give your thoughts on that?

Answer (score 0):

I have found it difficult to start from the code first approach when initially setting up the database.

One approach that is recommended by one of the EF ninjas (Julie Lerman) is that you start off with the database first approach after which you switch to code first (with migrations).

If you properly set up the database with PK and FK, you'll have the right domain classes as well if you use the DbContext generator in Visual Studio.